# Setting Application Menu name in GTK+/Python (fixing "Unknown Application Name")

Tags: python, ubuntu, menu, gtk

When running GTK+ apps under Ubuntu 12.04, how do you set the application name that is displayed in the Application-level menu?

Here's an example app:

```
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, Gio
import sys


class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        GLib.set_application_name('My App')
        self.app = Gtk.Application.new('org.example.test', 0)
        self.app.connect('startup', self.on_app_startup)
        self.app.connect('activate', self.on_app_activate)
        self.app.connect('shutdown', self.on_app_shutdown)

    def run(self, argv):
        self.app.run(argv)

    def on_app_startup(self, app):
        self.window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow.new(app)
        self.window.set_default_size(640, 480)
        self.window.set_title('AppMenu Demo')

        app.add_window(self.window)

        # # App menu
        app_menu = Gio.Menu()

        section = Gio.Menu()
        item = Gio.MenuItem.new('Quit', 'app.quit')
        item.set_attribute_value("accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>Q"))
        section.append_item(item)

        app_menu.append_section(None, section)

        app.set_app_menu(app_menu)

        # # Menu bar
        menu_bar = Gio.Menu()

        submenu = Gio.Menu()

        section = Gio.Menu()
        section.append_item(Gio.MenuItem.new('Help', 'app.help'))

        submenu.append_section(None, section)

        menu_bar.append_submenu('Help', submenu)

        app.set_menubar(menu_bar)

        action = Gio.SimpleAction.new('quit', None)
        action.connect('activate', self.on_quit)
        app.add_action(action)

    def on_app_activate(self, app):
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_app_shutdown(self, app):
        pass

    def on_quit(self, action, data=None):
        self.app.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

If you run this code under Ubuntu 12.04, it pops up a window labeled "AppMenu Demo"; the control bar at the top of the screen shows this name as well. If you move your mouse to the control bar, two pulldown menus are displayed; the app menu, and a "Help" menu.

This is all fine - except that the name of the Application menu is "Unknown Application Name". I can't find any way to alter this name. `GLib.set_application_name(name)` doesn't do it. How do you set the application name?

Or: is this a case where GTK+ is ahead of what Ubuntu supports? Google searches for "unknown application name" point at a range of bug reports and merged patches, which suggests to me that this might be an area of current development, rather than stable API. A quick survey of apps installed in Ubuntu shows that most apps have a "File" menu, but nothing that would be identified as an "app" menu of the type that GTK+ seems to support. Should I just abandon app menus until they're better supported at an OS level?

Answer (score 0):

It is a ubuntu specific/unity specific/ancient `gtk+ 3.4.x`/`gtk+ 3.6.x` bug.

With somewhat current (`gtk+ 3.10.7` and `Cinnamon 2.014` as DE) it works just fine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There's clearly more to it than this - Ubuntu 14.04 ships with GTK+ 3.10.8, and the problem still exists.

Comment: As said, it could be ubuntu specific bug that is introduced with Unity (or its AppIndicator thing).